# Ionic - The Email Address is Badly Formatted

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am working on an ionic project where I am using firebase as back-end and I am building a signup and login form. Whenever I sign up the code is working well and. When I try to retrieve it using "`signInWithEmailAndPassword`" I am getting the following error. The email address is badly formatted Firebase. When first time created account log in successfully. But after login with same email and password error occur.

```
import { Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, AlertController,  NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
 selector: 'page-signin',
 templateUrl: 'signin.html',
})

export class SigninPage {

 @ViewChild('email') email;
 @ViewChild('password') password;

constructor(public alertCon: AlertController, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
      console.log('ionViewDidLoad SigninPage');
    }

   alert(title, message){
    this.alertCon.create({
    title: title,
    subTitle: message,
    buttons: ['OK']
  }).present();
  }

  userSignin(){
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email.value, this.password.value)
 .then(data=>{
  console.log('loged in');
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
  this.alert('WELCOME', 'You are loged in');
})
 .catch(error=>{
  console.log('Error', error)
  this.alert('ERROR!', 'password or Email is wrong');
  });
 }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code you use to sign in a user?

Comment: Sorry!! My mistake..
I have edited post.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a User model in a separate folder. 
define the User model with the following way:

export interface User{
    id?: string
    email: string; 
    password:string;

### }

Then create a new obj of the User Model in LogIN ts file provided you have imported the model in the login ts file.

### user= {} as User;

You can make your login function
loginUser(user:User){    this.logauth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password);

### }

Angular works better if data is passed in an object rather than a property.
So the User Model in this aspect will hold the user data from the login html page and pass to the object in the  Login TS File. Hope this helps.

Comment: can you explain yourself better and  add some format to your code example ?

Comment: i Suggest you create a User Model, in a model folder.  export interface User{  
 id?: string;
 username: string; 
 email: string; 
 password:string;  
  roles: Roles; 

}